# ROBLOX [Lua] Tycoon - How do I change the type of object my machine creates?

Tags: object, colors, lua, scripting

Hey stackoverflow community! I am currently working on my own "Tycoon" game in ROBLOX. However, I have run into a small issue with the scripting.. so basically, when the player purchases a machine called a "Dropper", the "Dropper" will create gray cubes. The problem I have with this is that I want the gray cubes to be lime green neon spheres instead. I have tried multiple ways of fixing it but I have not figured it out yet. This is the script for the "Dropper" machine:

```
wait(2)
workspace:WaitForChild("PartStorage")


deb = true 
script.Parent.Clicker.ClickDetector.MouseClick:connect(function(wat)
if deb == true then
    deb = false
        local part = Instance.new("Part",workspace.PartStorage)
        part.BrickColor=script.Parent.Parent.Parent.DropColor.Value
        part.Material=script.Parent.Parent.Parent.MaterialValue.Value
        local cash = Instance.new("IntValue",part)
        cash.Name = "Cash"
        cash.Value = 1 -- How much the drops are worth
        part.CFrame = script.Parent.Drop.CFrame - Vector3.new(0,1.3,0)
        part.FormFactor = "Custom"
        part.Size=Vector3.new(1, 1, 1) -- Size of the drops
        part.TopSurface = "Smooth"
        part.BottomSurface = "Smooth"
        game.Debris:AddItem(part,20) -- How long until the drops expire
        wait(.15)
        deb = true
end
end)
```

To clarify, I want the script to spawn a Lime green Neon Sphere instead of the current gray block. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance,
E.W

Answer (score 0):

Somebody in a Discord server helped me figure it out! This is the solution:

```
wait(2)
workspace:WaitForChild("PartStorage")

deb = true 
script.Parent.Clicker.ClickDetector.MouseClick:connect(function(wat)
if deb == true then
    deb = false
        local part = Instance.new("Part",workspace.PartStorage)
        part.Shape = Enum.PartType.Ball
        part.BrickColor=BrickColor.new("Lime green")
        part.Material=script.Parent.Parent.Parent.MaterialValue.Value
        local cash = Instance.new("IntValue",part)
        cash.Name = "Cash"
        cash.Value = 1 -- How much the drops are worth
        part.CFrame = script.Parent.Drop.CFrame - Vector3.new(0,1.3,0)
        part.FormFactor = "Custom"
        part.Size=Vector3.new(1, 1, 1) -- Size of the drops
        part.TopSurface = "Smooth"
        part.BottomSurface = "Smooth"
        game.Debris:AddItem(part,20) -- How long until the drops expire
        wait(.15)
        deb = true
end
end)
```